# How to convert a numeric number in R to timestamp in R? For example, from 62280 to 17:18:00

Tags: r, time, timestamp

I have a RData file, one column in which is time. However, when I load it in R, it is shown in numbers.

For example, 17:18:00 is shown as 62280 , 
             06:30:00 is shown as 23400 ,
             18:30:00 is shown as 66600 ,
             10:30:00 is shown as 37800 ,
             01:00:00 is shown as 3600 .

I figure out number divided by 3600 is equal to time, as 23400/3600 = 6.5.

But I still stuck how to do in the next step. Could anyone give a clue? Also, is this "divided by 3600" is a standard time conversion in R? If so, is there a function for this conversion?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there code you have tried?  What do you currently have code-wise to be looked at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Using the chron package this gives a "times" class object or if you prefer character strings use `format(times(...))`.

```
library(chron)
x <- c(62280, 23400, 66600, 37800, 3600)
times(x / (24 * 60 * 60))
## [1] 17:18:00 06:30:00 18:30:00 10:30:00 01:00:00
```

**2)** Using POSIXct class and no packages we can get character strings like this:

```
format(as.POSIXct(x, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC"), "%H:%M:%S")
## [1] "17:18:00" "06:30:00" "18:30:00" "10:30:00" "01:00:00"
```